# .Net ajax post method Newtonsoft.Json assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, json.net

I have a Aspx web application in which I have a WebMethod that I'm calling from an Ajax post, the problem is that when doing the call, it throws me a:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

I already try to desintall and reinstall the Newtonsoft.Json nugget, but it doesn't work, the version that I have is 10.0.2, so I don't now why is looing for a 11.0 version, this is what I have on my web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "call.aspx/getToken",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        data = JSON.parse(data.d);

        apiKey = data[0].apiKey;
        sessionId = data[0].sessionId;
        token = data[0].token;

        initializeSession();

    }



});
```

And this is my webmethod:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string getToken()
    {

      //some code



        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListVar);
    }
```

Why could it be this error?

Comment: Do you have a using statement in your code behind? JsonConvert is not giving you an error?

Comment: Fwiw, I have the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my bin and no assembly binding in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could you please post the error message you receive when you try upgrading the Newtownsoft.Json package. Sounds like you might be trying to remove it when you have a dependency.

Secondly, if you receive an error indicating v11 is required, it is almost certainly due to one or more referenced components requiring that version.
Upgrading all referenced assemblies in your solution to v11+ is one option.
You may also want to consider referencing v11 in your assembly binding.

Try something like this perhaps:-

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Lets us know how you get on.